# Return custom class object from a WinForm derived class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Say, if I have my own data class defined as such:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string v1;
    public int v2;
    //etc.
}
```

I can pass it to my own Form-derived class and use it to initialize the form controls:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private MyData dataIn;

    public MyForm(MyData data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataIn = data;
    }
}

private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Init controls in 'MyForm' from 'dataIn'
}

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Save button was clicked

    //Read data from 'MyForm', but
    //how to return it back in 'MyData' class?

    //Close form
    this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

And the form itself is called as such:

```
//Initial data for the form
MyData data = new MyData(){
    v1 = "test",
    v2 = 123
};

MyForm dlg = new MyForm(data);
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //User clicked Save -- how to get data back in 'MyData'?
}
```

The issue is how to have my `MyData` to be filled with data and returned from `MyForm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a method for accessing the result data outside the form, either a property you can read or a method you can call from elsewhere:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private MyData dataIn;
    // Option 1: property that can be read from another class
    public MyData result { get; private set; }

    // Option 2: method you can call to get the result object
    public MyData GetResult()
    {
        return result;
    }

    public MyForm(MyData data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataIn = data;
    }

    private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // set result object
        result = new MyData { v1 = "some string value", v2 = 123 }

        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Then your caller does something similar to:

```
MyData dlgResult = null;
using (MyForm dlg = new MyForm(data))
{
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        dlgResult = dlg.GetResult();
}
if (dlgResult != null)
{
    // do something with the result
    //....
}
```

Note that `Form.Close()` does not dispose the form.  Until it *is* disposed, you can still perform operations on it.  The `using (MyForm...` syntax ensures that the form is correctly disposed once you're finished with it.

Comment: Thanks. I should go get some sleep... forgot about properties :)

Answer (score 0):

Create property of type `MyData` in MyForm:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private MyData dataIn;
    public MyData dataOut {get; set;}

    public MyForm(MyData data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataIn = data;
        dataOut = new MyData { v1 = "hi!", v2 = 2013 }; 
    }
}
```

Then you can read it:

```
MyForm dlg = new MyForm(data);
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    MyData dataFromForm = dlg.dataOut;
}
```